# How to identify north pole of a magnet using only a battery, and a copper wire?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I have a magnet, a copper wire, and a battery. I need to find the north pole, and the south pole of a magnet using only these items. (not a compass).

Here's my attempt:  create a circuit, battery is the electromotive force and electrons flow inside the copper wire from negative charges to positive charges.

Now, I can find direction of motion using right hand rule, (i.e unit vector of direction is equal to direction of my thumb).

Knowing the relationship between electric current and magnetic force, and knowing Faraday's law, I can easily say magnetic force is moving in the opposite direction. Therefore, I have north pole in the opposite direction of electric current, and south pole the other direction. Does it make sense? I'm afraid I've misinterpreted Faraday's law. Can Faraday's law be used like this?

Comment: As a check, nowing in your location roughly the direction of geographic North, why not "hang" your magnet using the copper wire and see which end of the magnet points North.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at this website, where a nice spinning wire experiment is shown:

https://www.fleet.org.au/blog/spinning-wire/